# locating macro code running on Excel open

Tags: vba, excel

Some years ago I programmed VBA to have my Excel (2010) open a specific workbook (serving as a library file) from a particular flash drive each time it opened.  I have recently replaced the flash drive system with a shared GoogleDrive.  When Excel opens, I get an error message that the shortcut to my file on the flash drive doesn't work - naturally.  I would like to change the path in my code, but, given my fading memory, can't find the code!  I don't see any in PERSONAL.XLSB and no macros are listed.  Where might it be?

Comment: Did you write an Add-in? Or in program files along with Excel.exe?

Comment: This is not a stack overflow question. Start here:

https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28047953/Where-does-Excel-store-bas-VBA-macro-code.html

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Customize-how-Excel-starts-6509b9af-2cc8-4fb6-9ef5-cf5f1d292c19

Comment: My wife solved it!  There was a second XLStart folder in ProgramFiles (x86).

Comment: in the future go to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ and download `process monitor`, run it, then open the excel file in question. the process monitor logs all hard drive accesses. from that you can figure out which files excel is opening.

Answer (score 1):

Are you certain you did this via VBA?
Usually, it is an option under

`File > Options > Advanced > General`

Or, in 2010, perhaps you just hit the `Office` button at the upper left.

[image]